# JavaPOS - Epson TM-T88IV - UnsatisfiedLinkError in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, printing, unsatisfiedlinkerror, epson, javapos

I bought an Epson TM-T88IV Thermal printer. I installed the Epson JavaPOS ADK by using the install manual.

Then I added the Jar-Files from the lib Folder of the Epson JavaPOS in Eclipse and wrote a simple Program which connects to the Printer.

```
public class MainClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        //System.out.println("Ausgabe aus der main()-Methode"); 

        POSPrinterControl113 ptr = (POSPrinterControl113)new POSPrinter();

        try {
            //Open the device.
            //Use the name of the device that connected with your computer.
            ptr.open("EPSON_TM_T88IV");

            //Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            //Then the device is disable from other application.
            ptr.claim(1000);

            //Enable the device.
            ptr.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        }
        catch(JposException ex) {
        }
    } 
}
```

But I'm receiving these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jp_co_epson_upos_firm_FirmNativeAccess_1_13_0001 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_13_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.<clinit>(CommonPrinterService.java:1004)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.epson.uposcommon.util.EpsonJposServiceInstanceFactory.createInstance(EpsonJposServiceInstanceFactory.java:142)
    at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(Unknown Source)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
```

It is possible to print something with the "CheckHealth.bat"

Has someone an Idea to solve this Problem?

Best regards

Meinzelmaenchen

- I'm using Windwos 8.1 (64-Bit)
- The Thermal Printer is connected by USB
- The Version of the EPSON JavaPOS ADK is 1.13.15
- Newest 32-Bit Java-Versions of the Java JDK and JAI are installed

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError means that Java can't find a needed System library. "System library" means in this case NOT a jar library. "System library" means a library file of the operating System (DLL on Windows).

You need to change the (on Windows) the PATH variable and add the correct Directory in which the needed Epson JavaPOS DLLs are stored. Or you can alternatively set the correct path while starting your Java application with the "-Djava.library.path" Parameter, e.g.:

```
java.exe -Djava.library.path=c:\path\to\dlls\ -cp c:\my\class\path my.app.Main
```

**EDIT**:

The path you need to specify is the directory in which the DLLs `jp_co_epson_upos_firm_FirmNativeAccess*.dll` are stored. The installation routine of the Epson JavaPOS ADK stored these files into the bin directory of the JRE which you have specify while installing the ADK.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to include dir with epson driver files (jp_co_epson_upos_firm_FirmNativeAccess_1_13_0001.XX) into class path, in centos for example you would need to go to /home/username/.bash_profile and add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/EpsonJavaPOS/bin